# How to open file in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to open a `.pdf` file after download which is downloaded with **Alamofire**. But I've seen only using a "webview". Thus the application consumes lots of memory and is not viable.

What I want is to open it with the native device application. Any suggestions? Thank you.

**Edit:** This is my code for download file:

```
    var localPath: NSURL?

    Alamofire.download(.GET, url, destination: { (temporaryURL, response) in
    let directoryURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
    let pathComponent = response.suggestedFilename
    localPath = directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent!)
    return localPath!
    })
    .response { (request, response, _, error) in

    if error != nil
    {
    // got an error in getting the data, need to handle it
    print("Error: \(error!)")

    }

    //print(response)
    print("Download file en:\(localPath!)")

    self.view.hideToastActivity()
    //self.actioncall()

    }

 }
```

I need open file from localpath...

Comment: Heard of UIDocumentInteractionController ever ?? If not try reading it. I believe thats what you need :) Happy coding :)

Comment: You should show what have you done already.

Comment: update op. I will read @SandeepBhandari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `UIDocumentInteractionController`. You can read about it on [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/) Apple documentation page.

By doing some Googling you should see even some example implementations. For example [here](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch23p802fileHandoff/ch36p1060fileHandoff/ViewController.swift) you can see some code about this done by "**mattneub**".

I let you one more code that you can use:

```
var documentInteractionController: UIDocumentInteractionController!

@IBAction func openDocument(sender: UIButton) {
  let URL: NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("yourPDF", withExtension: "pdf")!

    if (URL != "") {
        // Initialize Document Interaction Controller
        self.documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: URL)

        // Configure Document Interaction Controller
        self.documentInteractionController.delegate = self

        // Present Open In Menu
        self.documentInteractionController.presentOptionsMenuFromRect(sender.frame, inView: self.view, animated: true)
            //presentOpenInMenuFromRect
    }
}

// UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate
func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
    return self
}
```

Comment: crash in this line: let URL: NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("yourPDF", withExtension: "pdf")! ...error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value... thread 1 exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)

Comment: You had nil in the line. But happy to help. Happy coding :)

Comment: One more question. This works with a pdf file in the root directory of the application but if I use localpath(file:///Users/informatica/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6ABF0CE7-FE77-4D6F-9331-120A344B7396/data/Containers/Data/Application/847D3998-5A9D-4741-9A54-DC71C9225F98/Documents/109.pdf) It does not work or I did not implement it well.

I need a real device or can be performed with the emulator ?.

Comment: It is harder to perform it on simulator. Try on real device instead.